# download link for files stored on a website without DNS entry ( local host files )

Tags: html, file, host

I am developing a site that has no DNS RR yet.

I have modified the Windows host file so I can work with it.

Is it normal that the file is not downloaded when I click on the link?

```
<a href="http://mathieu-icstar.dev.univ-amu.fr/system/files/2019-10/SUFLE-emplois_du_temps_240919.pdf" type="application/pdf; length=919827" target="_blank">SUFLE-emplois_du_temps_240919.pdf</a>
```

when copying the `href` on a new window works.

Comment: No it is not normal. Look at the Network tab in the Developer Tools of your browser and look for errors.

Comment: i have nested links from an accordeon structure so that must be it. Thanks to help me exclude that possibility

Answer (score 1):

if you not using any framework to your make website then just use a variable for your public path instead of giving relative path to resources or links.

**constant.php**

```
<?php 
  define("PUBLIC_PATH", strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],0,5))=='https://'?'https://':'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__DIR__))).'/');     

?>
```

**index.php**

```
 <?php
     include "constant.php";
 ?>
 <a href="<?= PUBLIC_PATH ?>system/files/2019-10/SUFLE-emplois_du_temps_240919.pdf" type="application/pdf; length=919827" target="_blank">SUFLE-emplois_du_temps_240919.pdf</a>
```